# Что необходимо учесть для организации встречи сообщества?

Tags: поддержка, faq, встречи-сообщества

Я очень люблю Stack Overflow и хочу провести встречу участников сообщества в своем городе. Подскажите, что мне следует учесть? Какие шаги для организации необходимо сделать?

Answer (score 13):

Встреча с интересными увлеченными людьми – крайне приятное событие в жизни любого человека. Встреча с участниками Stack Overflow – приятное событие вдвойне. Проведение встречи не занимает много времени или сил и крайне просто по своей структуре. Все, что вам требуется – это желание и немного собранности. Планируя провести встречу, пожалуйста, учтите следующее.

#### Определите тип встречи

Можно выделить два вида встреч:

1. Встреча, на которой вы ожидаете увидеть ваших коллег из сообщества Stack Overflow.
2. Встреча, на которой вы планируете представлять сообщество Stack Overflow.

Главное отличие этих типов встреч в аудитории собравшихся. Так, во втором случае, с большой вероятность, организация встречи будет происходить за пределами инфраструктуры Stack Exchange и подчиняться своим правилам. Рекомендации ниже, по большей мере, относятся к первому типу встреч.

#### Что необходимо для создания встречи?

1. *Понять, есть ли у вас время и желание для организации встречи*. Организация любого мероприятия требует некоторого внимания с вашей стороны: именно вам будет необходимо потратить время на обсуждение места встречи, поиску помещения для встречи, договориться с владельцами помещения и решать непредвиденные проблемы, которые обязательно возникнут. Пожалуйста, рассчитывайте свои силы.
2. *Опубликовать вопрос на Мете*, который будет содержать место встречи (город), ориентировочную дату (месяц) проведение и форму для сбора откликов (пожалуйста, про сбор откликов читайте подробнее ниже).
3. *Создать чат*, для динамического обсуждения встречи.
4. *Активно принимать участие* во всех обсуждениях на Мете и чате, и своевременно заниматься возникающими организационными вопросами.

#### Сбор откликов: будьте особенно внимательны с личными данными

Помните о праве участников на деперсонализацию. Далеко не все участники хотят связывать свою активность в Интернете с активностью в реальной жизни. Это право каждого.

Во время встречи, пожалуйста, считайте, что по умолчанию участники не хотят, чтобы любая информация о них попала в интернет (включая фотографии и видео записи). Прежде чем сделать фотографию с кем–либо, поинтересуетесь не возражает ли он/она против этого.

*Внимательно подходите к сбору личных данных для встречи*. Из нашего опыта организации встреч, *единственное обязательное поле для ввода личных данных – это ссылка на учетную запись на одном из сайтов Stack Overflow*. Для всего остального: (1) следует использовать не обязательные к заполнению поля; (2) следует явно указать, как будет использоваться собранная информация.

Пожалуйста, **в явном виде укажите, что организатор именно вы, участник сообщества, и именно вы, как организатор, собираете личные данные**. Многие участники могут не понимать, что откликаясь они передают свои личные данные именно вам, а не компании.

Пожалуйста, укажите в явном виде, зачем вам эти данные – это повысит доверие к вам, а как результат, вероятность откликов. *Не запрашивайте личные данные, которые на самом деле не нужны для встречи.* **Ни в коем случае не используйте собранные данные ни для каких целей, кроме как для организации мероприятия.**

Если ваша форма сбора откликов не будет отвечать требованиями приватности, мы будем вынуждены удалить ссылку на сбор откликов и остановить организацию встречи.

<sub>Помните, главная цель встречи – знакомство и дружелюбное общение участников сообщества Stack Overflow в реальной жизни. Ни в коем случае не допускайте, чтобы встреча участников вышла за эти рамки. Если позже станет известно о корыстных мотивах сбора участников сообщества, мы будем вынуждены применить соответствующие санкции к организатору встречи.</sub>

**Рекомендуемые вопросы для анкеты**

- Ссылка на учётную запись на Stack Overflow (обязательным к заполнению полем).
- Варианты удобной даты проведения встречи.
- Варианты удобного времени проведения встречи.
- Варианты удобного места проведения встречи.
- Варианты желаемого формата встречи. Например: формат докладов, антикафе и настольные игры, бар и т.д.
- Поле для указания личных пожеланий.
- Дополнительные поля. Например, размер футболки (в случае, если вы заранее свяжитесь с [управляющим сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) и уточните о возможности своевременной отправки вам нужного количества футболок).

Для сбора анкет мы рекомендуем использовать Google Forms.

#### Процесс организации

Организация встречи полностью ложится на плечи автора вопроса о встрече на Мете. Именно Вам предстоит проделать все необходимые подготовительные мероприятия.

Как только место, время, тематика и список участников встречи определятся окончательно (например, по завершению допустимого времени подачи отклика), вам необходимо написать на почту [управляющему сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile), передав собранную информацию. Он сделает необходимую рассылку на основе предоставленных вами данных и указанных почтовых адресов в учетной записи на Stack Overflow.

С большой вероятностью (основываясь на нашем опыте), будет необходимо сделать несколько рассылок:

1. По итогам сбора анкет.
2. За день до мероприятия.
3. За несколько часов до встречи.

Если у вас есть соображения на этот счет, не стесняйтесь об этом написать в личной переписке управляющему.

#### Помощь компании

Если вы считаете, что компания Stack Overflow как–либо может помочь вам в организации встречи, пожалуйста, напишите об этом [управляющему сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) или свяжитесь с командой развития сообществ через [форму обратной связи](/contact).

Например, пришедшие на встречу участники, были бы рады небольшим памятным сувенирам (наклейкам, футболкам, ручкам и т.д.), которые мы будем рады отправить вам совершенно бесплатно.

Если вам нужна какая–либо консультация, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь связаться с кем–либо из команды развития сообществ для получения дополнительной помощи.

#### Личная ответственность

Вся ответственность за проведение мероприятия ложится на его организатора. Провал в организации встречи – удар по вашей репутации.

Если перед мероприятием ваши жизненные планы кардинально поменялись, что случается, пожалуйста, сообщайте об этом всем заинтересованным во встрече участникам.

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить пару пунктов об управлении последствием встречи. Например, фото со встречи и деперсонализация; что стоит рассказать организатору (организационные ошибки и их решения, какие плюсы и чему научились, завербовали ли в братство Кольца и SO кого-нибудь своим примером, etc).

Comment: Кстати да, аренда помещения/арены - не самое дешёвое удовольствие, особенно в больших городах. Как тут компания может помочь? Или только футболками (что, конечно, приятно).

Comment: @Other Вопрос о фотографиях лучше решать лично на месте: для кого–то это приятные воспоминание, а кто–то действительно не хочет попасть в сеть (я знаю многих таких людей). Тут следует руководствоваться нормами этикета.

Comment: Поэтому я и сказал - нужно осветить этот вопрос в Вашем гайде юного организатора.

Comment: @Other Если не брать в расчет платные конференции, я не знаю встреч, на которых бы организаторы оплачивали аренду. Обычно, если встречи проходят в формате докладов, найдется много компаний, которые с радостью предложат вам провести встречу у них (а заодно и посмотреть на их прекрасные условия работы!) Формат бара или антикафе не предусматривает какую–либо аренду. Думаю, для хороших участников, компания с радостью закажет пиццу за свой счет :)

Comment: @Other Добавил про фотографии.

Comment: Вот тут и соль - кто-то может не знать как правильно организовать подобную встречу (что-то, что сложнее "собираемся в кафе, выпьём виноградной газировки"). Может стоит подробнее передать Ваш опыт?

Comment: @Other местные IT-компании встанут в очередь за возможностью предоставить помещение. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если покажешь нотариально заверенный скриншот о том, что это действительно SO, наверное.

Comment: @Other, например в Санкт-Петербурге Yandex, Luxoft, Data Art, Wrike и SEMRush замечены в предоставлении пространства (зала со стульями и проектором) для проведения образовательных встреч IT-сообществ. Как правило это предполагает, что среди докладчиков будет кто-то принимающей компании и будет в своем докладе пиарить её так или иначе.

Comment: @Nofate, это я уже понял. Только это устанавливает рамки, довольно жёсткие, если подумать. Обязательно формат, который позволяет восхвалять принимающую сторону, например.